# Image and Equations

Tags: floats, equations, align, wrapfigure

I want to introduce equation and image, to save space, For example on one side equations and another side your photo.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! So, what is the question?

Comment: There are two problems with combining wrapfigure and equations.  The first is that equations use trivlist and there are problems with lists in general.  Perhaps more important is that equations count as single line of text, but are generally much larger than \baselineskip in size, so wrapfig keeps going too long.

Comment: the best method i know of so far is to put the equations in a minipage that can be set next to the graphic in another minipage.

Comment: if you wish the equations to always be next to the same figure you can try using subfloats

Answer (score 3):

You may try some variations on the theme below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\usepackage{lipsum}% for context

\DeclareMathOperator{\Rang}{Rang}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[2]
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.6\columnwidth}
\centering
$\begin{aligned}[t]
&\iff f(x)\ge-1,\quad \forall x\in\mathbf{R} \\
&\iff f(x)\in [1,\infty) \\
&\iff \Rang(f)=[1,\infty)
\end{aligned}$
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{.4\columnwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,valign=t]{example-image}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution using subfloats:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}      % images and PDFs
\usepackage{subfig}        % subfigures w/ captions

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[tbp]
        \subfloat{        
        $
        a = \frac{D {U}}{Dt}
        $
        }
        \hfill
        \subfloat[Description]{\includegraphics[trim=0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm, clip, height=3cm]{./figures/xxx.jpg}}

        %\caption[xxx]{xxx}
        \label{fig:xxx}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

You don't want a 'normal' caption, so you have to go with the subfloat description for the image. This has the downsight of a random '(b)' appearing. Only solution I know would be to put the image left and get an '(a)'.